# How do I replace the port number in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of strings, and I want to create a new array which contains the same strings without port numbers (the port number is a ":" followed by a number). For example if the string is "http://www.example.com:8080/hello/" Then it should be replaced with "http://www.example.com/hello/". How do I do it in JavaScript? I need it to call safari.extension.addContentScriptFromURL because the whitelist can't contain port numbers. If possible, it's better to replace the port number only between the second and third slash and leave the rest of the string unchanged.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644654/parse-url-with-jquery-javascript You'd need to split the URL into components, replace the port component and re-assemble the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I used your answer and changed it a little, because the protocol may contain dashes too:

```
var newUrls = urls.map(function(url) {
    return url.replace(/([^\/\:]+):\/\/([^\/]+):([0-9]+)\//, "$1://$2/");
})
```

Answer (score 20):

You don't need any library or REGEX

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

```js
var url = new URL('http://localhost:8080');
url.port = '';
console.log(url.toString());
```

Regrards

Comment: FYI - Internet Explorer doesn't support this `URL` functionality

Comment: You can use an polyfill

https://polyfill.io/v3/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48447629/new-urllocation-href-doesnt-work-in-ie

Comment: you can use Chrome Explorer

Answer (score 4):

One quite nifty way to do this, is to create an `a` element, and assign the URL you have as `href` - because [the `HTMLAnchorElement` interface implements `URLUtils`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement), and therefor supports accessing the individual parts of the address in the same way the `location` object does, and you can *set* them individually as well:

```
var foo = document.createElement("a");
foo.href = "http://www.example.com:8080/hello/";
foo.port = ""
var newURL = foo.href;
console.log(newURL); // output: http://www.example.com/hello/
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pdymeb5d/

Answer (score 3):

This should probably do what you want:

```
var newUrls = urls.map(function (url) {
    return url.replace(/([a-zA-Z+.\-]+):\/\/([^\/]+):([0-9]+)\//, "$1://$2/");
});
```

Edit: It seems the schema part of URIs can contain "+", "." and "-" also. Changed the regular expression accordingly.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex with string.replace() as follows,

```
var text = "http://www.example.com:8080/hello/";
var withNoDigits = text.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
var outputString = withNoDigits.replace(/:([^:]*)$/,'$1');
alert(outputString);
```

Comment: The domain may contain digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function parseURL(url) {
        var parser = document.createElement('a'),
            searchObject = {},
            queries, split, i;
        parser.href = url;

        queries = parser.search.replace(/^?/, '').split('&');
        for( i = 0; i < queries.length; i++ ) {
            split = queries[i].split('=');
            searchObject[split[0]] = split[1];
        }
        return {
            protocol: parser.protocol,
            host: parser.host,
            hostname: parser.hostname,
            port: parser.port,
            pathname: parser.pathname,
            search: parser.search,
            searchObject: searchObject,
            hash: parser.hash


 };
}
```

Use this to parse any URL and arrange in a format you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found best solution here.

`var url = 'http://localhost:7001/www.facebook.com';
// Create a regex to match protocol, domain, and host
var matchProtocolDomainHost = /^.*\/\/[^\/]+:?[0-9]?\//i;
// Replace protocol, domain and host from url, assign to`myNewUrl
`var myNewUrl = url.replace(matchProtocolDomainHost, '');`
Now myNewUrl === 'www.facebook.com'.

Better to read full page.
[remove hostname and port from url using regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550790/remove-hostname-and-port-from-url-using-regular-expression)