# new URL(location.href) doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am facing to problem with method new URL('address') in IE.

I have this code:

```
var href =  location.href;
var hrefParams = new URL(href);
var api = hrefParams.searchParams.get("api");
```

In Firefox and Chrome it works at should and I will get the value of attribute "api".

But in IE I am getting error on console:

> SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action

Console error debugger points to the problem with line

```
var hrefParams = new URL(href);
```

For solving of another problem I already invoking script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bluebird.min.js"></script>
```

But it doesn't fix this problem.

Any idea how to fix it in IE?

Comment: IE doesn't support the URL API.  The Bluebird library doesn't add support for that.

Comment: `window.URL` is only available in Edge (and all other non-IE browsers)

Comment: Look at MDN documentation, it has support tables https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 21, accepted):

At the end I have fixed that by this code:

```
function getQueryString() {
          var key = false, res = {}, itm = null;
          // get the query string without the ?
          var qs = location.search.substring(1);
          // check for the key as an argument
          if (arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0].length > 1)
            key = arguments[0];
          // make a regex pattern to grab key/value
          var pattern = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g;
          // loop the items in the query string, either
          // find a match to the argument, or build an object
          // with key/value pairs
          while (itm = pattern.exec(qs)) {
            if (key !== false && decodeURIComponent(itm[1]) === key)
              return decodeURIComponent(itm[2]);
            else if (key === false)
              res[decodeURIComponent(itm[1])] = decodeURIComponent(itm[2]);
          }

          return key === false ? res : null;
}
```

...

```
        var api = getQueryString('api');
```

I forgot where I found that but it is working as I needed.

Answer (score 15):

IE does not support `URL`. You will have to add a polyfill for it.

Comment: How can I? Is any demonstration

Comment: Adding `<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js"></script>` worked best for me

Comment: I solved by adding this line to the head of the page:     <script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=URL"></script>

Answer (score 12):

Another solution I've been using if anyone is interested

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
  var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
      results = regex.exec(location.search);
  return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

getParameterByName('api');
```

Comment: Awesome function! Worked for me!

Answer (score 7):

Add `polyfill` cdn script

```
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

This method is not supported by IE

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL#AutoCompatibilityTable

you should use a lib like jquery deparam or retrieve the parameters with String.split() method or use this function that I made:

```js
function decodeUriComponentWithSpace (component) {
    return decodeURIComponent(component.replace(/\+/g, '%20'))
  }

  // type : 'hash', 'search' or 'both'
  function getLocationParameters (location, type) {
    if (type !== 'hash' && type !== 'search' && type !== 'both') {
      throw 'getLocationParameters expect argument 2 "type" to be "hash", "search" or "both"'
    }

    let searchString = typeof location.search === 'undefined' ? '' : location.search.substr(1)
    let hashString = typeof location.hash === 'undefined' ? '' : location.hash.substr(1)
    let queries = []
    if (type === 'search' || type === 'both') {
      queries = queries.concat(searchString.split('&'))
    }
    if (type === 'hash' || type === 'both') {
      queries = queries.concat(hashString.split('&'))
    }

    let params = {}
    let pair

    for (let i = 0; i < queries.length; i++) {
      if (queries[i] !== '') {
        pair = queries[i].split('=')
        params[this.decodeUriComponentWithSpace(pair[0])] = this.decodeUriComponentWithSpace(pair[1])
      }
    }
    return params
}

   // TEST: 
window.location.hash = 'test=a&test2=b'
console.log(getLocationParameters(window.location, 'both'))
```

Answer (score 4):

Pure Javascript solution, so you can run it in IE as well without bothering with polyfills:

```
   function getUrlVars() {
        var vars = {};
        var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
            vars[key] = value;
        });
        return vars;
    }
```

Comes from this page: https://html-online.com/articles/get-url-parameters-javascript/

Answer (score 3):

For the purposes of my project, I've created this script, which I think also could work for you or someone else who has a problem with IE11 and the lack of support for the URL method.

```
        /* Polyfill URL method IE 11 */

        // ES5

        if (typeof window.URL !== 'function') {
            window.URL = function (url) {
                var protocol = url.split('//')[0],
                    comps = url.split('#')[0].replace(/^(https\:\/\/|http\:\/\/)|(\/)$/g, '').split('/'),
                    host = comps[0],
                    search = comps[comps.length - 1].split('?')[1],
                    tmp = host.split(':'),
                    port = tmp[1],
                    hostname = tmp[0];

                search = typeof search !== 'undefined' ? '?' + search : '';

                var params = search
                    .slice(1)
                    .split('&')
                    .map(function (p) { return p.split('='); })
                    .reduce(function (p, c) {
                        var parts = c.split('=', 2).map(function (param) { return decodeURIComponent(param); });
                        if (parts.length == 0 || parts[0] != param) return (p instanceof Array) && !asArray ? null : p;
                        return asArray ? p.concat(parts.concat(true)[1]) : parts.concat(true)[1];
                    }, []);

                return {
                    hash: url.indexOf('#') > -1 ? url.substring(url.indexOf('#')) : '',
                    protocol: protocol,
                    host: host,
                    hostname: hostname,
                    href: url,
                    pathname: '/' + comps.splice(1).map(function (o) { return /\?/.test(o) ? o.split('?')[0] : o; }).join('/'),
                    search: search,
                    origin: protocol + '//' + host,
                    port: typeof port !== 'undefined' ? port : '',
                    searchParams: {
                        get: function(p) {
                            return p in params? params[p] : ''
                        },
                        getAll: function(){ return params; }
                    }
                };
            }
        }

        // ES6, in case of using Babel in a project

        if( typeof window.URL !== 'function' ){
            window.URL = function(url){
                let protocol = url.split('//')[0],
                    comps = url.split('#')[0].replace(/^(https\:\/\/|http\:\/\/)|(\/)$/g, '').split('/'),
                    host = comps[0],
                    search = comps[comps.length - 1].split('?')[1],
                    tmp = host.split(':'), 
                    port = tmp[1], 
                    hostname = tmp[0];

                search = typeof search !== 'undefined'? '?' + search : '';

                const params = search
                                    .slice(1)
                                    .split('&')
                                    .map(p => p.split('='))
                                    .reduce((obj, pair) => {
                                        const [key, value] = pair.map(decodeURIComponent);
                                        return ({ ...obj, [key]: value })
                                    }, {});

                return {
                    hash: url.indexOf('#') > -1? url.substring(url.indexOf('#')) : '',
                    protocol,
                    host,
                    hostname,
                    href: url,
                    pathname: '/' + comps.splice(1).map(function(o){ return /\?/.test(o)? o.split('?')[0] : o; }).join('/'),
                    search,
                    origin: protocol + '//' + host,
                    port: typeof port !== 'undefined'? port : '',
                    searchParams: {
                        get: p => p in params? params[p] : '',
                        getAll: () => params
                    }
                };
            }
        }
        /* Polyfill IE 11 end */

        new URL('http://localhost:8080/?a=1&b=3&c=z#123').searchParams.get('c'); // this will return "z"
```

But if it doesn't work for you, you could take I think full suported and polifilled function from this package here on the url:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-polyfill

Comment: I personally find this like the best answer here, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here's another polyfill specifically for the URL api, intended to work exactly as it does in modern browsers and only run if needed. This way you don't need to use a separate function that will be obsolete once you decide to drop support for IE.

`<script src="https://gist.github.com/ryangoree/def0a520ed43c6c465d9a6518161bc7c.js"></script>`

**Gist Page**:
https://gist.github.com/ryangoree/def0a520ed43c6c465d9a6518161bc7c

Answer (score 1):

modified @ales code for getting the value of a particular parameter. The default value is set to `false`.

```
function getUrlVars(index) {
  var vars = {};
  window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function (
    m,
    key,
    value
  ) {
    vars[key] = value;
  });

  if (index) {
    return vars[index] || false;
  }
  return vars;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed one like this and then un-needed it :). So I'll post it here

```js
var urlRegex = /(.*:)\/\/(.*?)(\/.*?)(\?.*?|#.*?|$)(#.*|$)/

function parseUrl(url) {
  var parts = urlRegex.exec(url)
  var search = parts[4]
  var hash = parts[5]
  if (!search.startsWith('?')) {
    hash = search
    search = ''
  }
  if (!hash.startsWith('#')) {
    hash = ''
  }
  return {
    protocol: parts[1],
    host: parts[2],
    pathname: parts[3],
    search,
    hash,
    searchParams: search
      .replace(/^\?/, '')
      .split('&')
      .reduce((params, kv) => {
          var kvPair = kv.split('=')
          params[kvPair[0]] = kvPair[1]
          return params
        }, {})
  }
}
```