# How to remove "localhost:3000" when fetching URLs

Tags: javascript, localhost, fetch, config

I have deployed a website and lets say the url is https://google.com

When im testing the javascript on localhost:3000, when I do

`fetch("https://google.com/config.json")`

it will fetch
`"localhost:3000/google.com/config.json"`
instead.

How do i make it so it will fetch "https://google.com/config.json" only(basically removing the localhost so i can test things work on my website without redeploying it?

Comment: it shouldn't do that unless you have some strange version of fetch or didn't include the `https://`

Comment: im using a react file and i npm start the file. On my localhost:3000 i console.logged the fetch and gave me localhost:3000/google.com/config.json

Comment: Well, you could use regex to remove it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550790/remove-hostname-and-port-from-url-using-regular-expression

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]